# Errors with software Installation

Tags: installation, windows-error-reporting, software-conflict

I am using windows 8.1.I have quick heal antivirus pro Installed.
**MY Problem**When i try to install **Free Download Maneger(FDM)** I have the error like following.

**First Error** IPresistFile:Save Failed Code 0x80070005 appears During the installation

[image: This is not real screenshot i have taken it from the Internet,But error words are same]

**Second Error** When i try to run the software after installation.
This Error appears 
[image: This is not real screenshot i have taken it from the Internet,But error words are same]

**Note** Images are not real screenshot, i have taken then from the Internet,But They depict the exact error as mine

Any and all help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You've problem with FDM but your screenshot shows setup of  EasyWorship 6. The problem may be in the installer C++ code (IPersistFile class and Save function). Did you contact developer website?

Comment: @Biswapriyo As i have mentioned in the question that images are not real screenshots.I have taken them from the internet to make my problem more clear .The same error message apppears when i try to install FDM

Answer (score 1):

What is the specific file that the installer is trying to create while you get the error message?
If the setup is able to install other files, maybe the NTFS permissions of the folder where it wants to install the file are messed up.
Is the installer being executed with elevated permissions? Please try to right-click the installer and run it with "Run as Administrator"
The second error is most likely due to the installer not being able to install all files.

I know this could also be a comment but I don't have the reputation to comment yet.

Comment: I don't know that file because installer runs very quickly and suddenly error appears,installer skips that file and creates other very quickly and progress bar goes red and full-filled.

Comment: You could use procmon from Sysinternals to check which files the installer is having problems with.